# Как спарсить динамический контент python?

Tags: python, парсер

Я парсю python-ом сайт https://www.flashscore.com/, а именно - матчи, которые в онлайне (live). Все матчи находятся в блоке `div` с `id="live-table"`. Добавление матчей в блок `div` происходит динамически.

Помогите, пожалуйста, получить доступ к списку `div`? Желательно не используя selenium, ибо у меня не получается установить драйвер для браузера, так как у меня стоит ubuntu.

Можно ли спарсить динамический контент с использованием модуля `requests`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открой через браузер, там открой "инспектировать элемент", перезагрузи страничку и смотри вкладку Network. На этом сайте на главной стоит web-socket соединение с зашифрованными данными. На дополнительных страницах стоит полинг - сайт постоянно дергает определенный урл и получает данные. Но и там содержимое зашифрованно.

Гол выглядит так

```
/fs/fs3_u_1_1SA÷1¬~AA÷xxSiad7m¬SCA÷1590704042¬~A2÷1588627646¬~L@^ '2
/fs/fs3_u_1_1SA÷1¬~AA÷xxSiad7m¬SCA÷0¬AG÷2¬BC÷1¬~L`^ '2
```

Хотя это не совсем шифр, а скорее бинарная структура. Но как её разобрать - надо смотреть в коде сайта.

Единственный метод - использовать большой браузер и [`Selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Оххх же черти... Понятно) Спасибо тебе огромное) Да, я уже использую Selenium, а то другого выхода не находил